# No styling or icons appear when I use a mdbreact component - Footer

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-design, font-awesome, mdbreact

I am building a simple landing page and wanted to make a footer component for the same. I used the npm command `npm install --save mdbreact` to install the dependency and copied the following snippet of code from the mdb website.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Col, Container, Row, Footer } from 'mdbreact';

export class FooterPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Footer color="stylish-color-dark" className="page-footer font-small pt-4 mt-4">
                <Container className="text-left">
                    <Row>
                        <Col md="6">
                            <h5 className="text-uppercase mb-4 mt-3 font-weight-bold">Footer Content</h5>
                            <p>Here you can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                            amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </Col>
                        <hr className="clearfix w-100 d-md-none" />
                        <Col md="2">
                            <h5 className="text-uppercase mb-4 mt-3 font-weight-bold">Links</h5>
                            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </Col>
                        <hr className="clearfix w-100 d-md-none" />
                        <Col md="2">
                            <h5 className="text-uppercase mb-4 mt-3 font-weight-bold">Links</h5>
                            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </Col>
                        <hr className="clearfix w-100 d-md-none" />
                        <Col md="2">
                            <h5 className="text-uppercase mb-4 mt-3 font-weight-bold">Links</h5>
                            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
                <hr />
                <div className="text-center py-3">
                    <ul className="list-unstyled list-inline mb-0">
                        <li className="list-inline-item">
                            <h5 className="mb-1">Register for free</h5>
                        </li>
                        <li className="list-inline-item"><a href="#" className="btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Sign up!</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div className="text-center">
                    <ul className="list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li className="list-inline-item"><a className="btn-floating btn-sm btn-fb mx-1"><i className="fa fa-facebook"> </i></a></li>
                        <li className="list-inline-item"><a className="btn-floating btn-sm btn-tw mx-1"><i className="fa fa-twitter"> </i></a></li>
                        <li className="list-inline-item"><a className="btn-floating btn-sm btn-gplus mx-1"><i className="fa fa-google-plus"> </i></a></li>
                        <li className="list-inline-item"><a className="btn-floating btn-sm btn-li mx-1"><i className="fa fa-linkedin"> </i></a></li>
                        <li className="list-inline-item"><a className="btn-floating btn-sm btn-dribbble mx-1"><i className="fa fa-dribbble"> </i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="footer-copyright text-center">
                    <Container fluid>
                        &copy; {(new Date().getFullYear())} Copyright: <a href="https://www.MDBootstrap.com"> MDBootstrap.com </a>
                    </Container>
                </div>
            </Footer>
        );
    }
}

export default FooterPage;
```

Now the problem is that the component appears on the main page but with no styling or icons. 
What it should look like:
[image: Footer Expectation]

How it actually looks: 
[image: Footer Reality]

Can someone help me with how to get the styles and icons working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add ---- import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css' ----

[image]

[image]

they may be some deviation in icon's because am using old icon set.

Also to get the icons to work you need to install fontawesome package using
`npm install --save react-fontawesome`
And then include it's CSS using the following line
`import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! The CSS works now but the icons still don't appear for some reason. Do I need to import font awesome as well via some statement?

Comment: Oh yeah! I had to `npm install --save react-fontawesome` and  include `import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';` to get the icons to work.